# Kotlin native not compiling properly with Gradle

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

I build my first KN as below, `gradle init`, then updating the `build.gradle` with the code below, then running `gradle build`, using my Mac:

`build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://dl.bintray.com/jetbrains/kotlin-native-dependencies"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-native-gradle-plugin:+"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'konan'

// Compile this component for 64-bit MacOS, Linux and Windows.
 konan.targets = [
                'wasm32',
                'android_arm32', 'android_arm64',
               //  'mingw_x64',
                //  'linux_x64', 'linux_arm32_hfp',
                 'macos_x64',
               //  'ios_x64', 'ios_arm32', 'ios_arm64'
                 ]

konanArtifacts {
    library('utils') {
        srcFiles fileTree('src/libs/utils')
    }
    program('hello') {
        libraries {
            artifact 'utils'
        }
    }
}
```

My app structure is:

[image: ![kn|249x366](upload://86qqoABKdE1jIJ2kl08UegGq2FR.png)]

`hello.kt` (app):

```
fun main() {
    println("Hello Gradle!")
}
```

`foo.kt` (lib):

```
fun foo(){
    println("Hello Gradle! again")
}
```

by running `gradle build`: I got the libs and executables as in the below tree:

[image]

I've the below questions:

1. Nothing had been generated for the following targets, this is why I made them as comments:
   iOS: ios_x64, ios_arm32, ios_arm64
   Raspberry: linux_arm32_hfp
   Windows: mingw_x64
   Linux: linux_x64
2. Are all the generated libraries `utils.Klib` are same, so I can pick anyone of them and use it anywhere, or I've to pick as per the required target.
3. How to call the function `foo` that is part of the library in the `main` function, I tried `import utils` then calling `utils.foo()` but did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle DSL for the new Kotlin multiplatform model is described here: http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html

(sorry for a separate thread, I just don't have enough reputation to leave a comment on the existing one)

Answer (score 1):

1. Please read the release notes document, describing which targets supported on which host: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/master/RELEASE_NOTES.md#supported-platforms
2. Nope, please use per-target .klib
3. To use the library you need to tell compiler so, i.e. `-l utils.klib` for command line or `library` DSL verb.

Also it's recommended to use new multiplatform Gradle DSL, not he one you use here.

Comment: Thanks, any link where can I find clear info about the new multiple platform Gradle DSL.